# localdb RESTORE SQL works on my Win 10 box, but not my Azure pipeline agent

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, azure-devops-server

I have an Azure pipeline that refuses to run my integration tests (well, prior to running the tests, it must create necessary databases from .bak files - and that's the part that is failing)

This SQL is being invoked as part of my MSTest `ClassInitialize` routine:

```sql
IF DB_ID('saleslogix_full') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN

      ALTER DATABASE [saleslogix_full] SET SINGLE_USER WITH
      ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

      DROP DATABASE [saleslogix_full];

    END

restore database saleslogix_full
from disk = 'C:\x\y\z\data-snapshots\saleslogix_full.bak' with Recovery,
move 'saleslogix_full' to 'C:\x\y\z\saleslogix_full.mdf',
move 'saleslogix_full_log' to 'C:\x\y\z\saleslogix_full_log.ldf'
```

The above is invoked by connecting to the 'master' datatbase of the `(localdb)\MSSQLLocal` server. Again, "works on my machine" running Visual Studio 2019. But, doesn't work on either of these Azure agents: `windows-2019` and `vs2017-win2016`

---

> Additional Details - Azure Agent Log Snippet

```
A total of 6 test files matched the specified pattern.
  X SeededSuccessfully_SalesforceIntegration
  Error Message:
   Class Initialization method MyCorp.Data.ReplicationWorker.Tests.Test1.ClassInit threw exception. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot create more than one clustered index on table 'dbo.sysschemaarticles'. Drop the existing clustered index 'PK_dbo.sysschemaarticles' before creating another.
Database 'saleslogix_full' was restored, however an error was encountered while replication was being restored/removed. The database has been left offline. See the topic MSSQL_ENG003165 in SQL Server Books Online.
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
Processed 1120 pages for database 'saleslogix_full', file 'saleslogix_full' on file 1.
Processed 2 pages for database 'saleslogix_full', file 'saleslogix_full_log' on file 1..
```

---

Now the jewel buried in the above log message is: 
`Cannot create more than one clustered index on table 'dbo.sysschemaarticles'. Drop the existing clustered index 'PK_dbo.sysschemaarticles' before creating another`

Before I go digging into how to do this, can anyone point me in a direction as to *why this works on my Windows 10 box but not my Azure pipeline agent?* My initial gut is to say it's a difference in "localdb" SQL editions

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to think it's due to the .bak file being specific to my box after reading [MSSQL_ENG003165 in SQL Server Books Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/mssql-eng003165?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting a `try{...}catch{..}` around my .NET code that was responsible for the bombing SQL statement.

The catch is specific to a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` error

Within the catch, I execute this SQL:

```
"ALTER DATABASE saleslogix_full SET ONLINE"
```

And all my integration tests seem to pass against the database